# Testing in Firefox 3.6 (testing platform?)

Tags: debugging, firefox, browser, firefox3.6

1.Do you have any ideas on how to test websites in firefox 3.6 if I have win7 and ff6 installed? I've tried to install 3.6 and alongside with ff 6 but it gets all messy.
Is there something like [Ie tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) for fire fox 3.6? Adobe lab-browser sucks because it's not "live".
2.How do you test your sites? (apart from the mentioned above)
3.If any one has ff 3.6 (and fire bug) could check this site and tell me what's wrong? http://dissbike.pl/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use portable version of Firefox from PortableApps.com, in this way you don't need any Virtual Machine. There are versions from 1.0 to 3.6 that can help to test your websites.

[>> Link here <<](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable#legacy)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a virtual machine, like Virtual Box with Ubuntu (or Windows if needed), then you could just download the required package or build Firefox from source.

BTW: you can currently find the version here: 
http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-older.html

Comment: then you may try to install this version in another directory

Comment: you can create a separate profile for another version, it will have no addons and will work like a vanilla install. Here you can find some info: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles. After you create a new profile you can make a shortcut on desktop to always launch each version in different profile.

Comment: I'm not fully sure, but probably a shortcut like `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 3\firefox.exe" -P -no-remote` will make it possible to launch two different instances of Firefox not trying to connect with each other (normally when you have one Firefox running, you cannot run the second, you will get message "Firefox already running", it will launch a new tab or window but within the same process).

Comment: to much hustle with changing profiles...in the end it all get messed up, but thx!